# A bad guitar... CAN it sound good?

Tags: guitar, classical-music

is it possible to have a beautiful agreeable good sound to dance or to rhythm the night while using a cheap $70 guitar (the classical guitar). Is the instruments responsible for it or it depends just of the musician ? Any minds ? thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 9):

There is a reason that instruments including cheap ones are showcased by expert players.  Famously, Paganini, getting tired of having his prowess attributed to his "magic" violin, one evening after a concert earning thunderous applause broke his instrument in pieces to a flabbergasted audience.  It had been a cheap instrument he got for that occasion.

A cheap instrument will make its player work a lot more for getting an agreeable sound out, but it's not beyond possibility.

Now $70 is really asking for it.  For a used instrument, you might have a chance.  For something costing $70 when new, this will be tricky.  Your best bet is when it is brand new and has not yet have had opportunity to warp its machine-milled neck: once that has happened, the instrument is no longer playable sensibly even by professionals.

Also it helps if you don't have to fill a concert hall with your sound and put on reasonable strings.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, the only limiting factors for a magic performance on a dirt cheap instrument are the skills of the guitarist and whether the guitar's intonation is correct (whether it can be played in tune).